# How to use django-ckeditor in frontend forms?

Tags: django

I'm working with Django. To integrate a Rich Text Editor with my site, I use the django-CKEditor from [https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor](http://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor)

While it works quite fine in the Admin Panel, I'd like to use it in frontend forms to allow the users of my website to edit their own texts via CKEditor. But I can not figure it out...

Is it true that this django-ckeditor can only be used in Admin Panel? If it isn't true, how to make it available in the frontend? Or any recommendation for other Rich Text Editor which I can use at the frontend?

Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just include `ckeditor` in static/js and apply it to whichever fields I need.

I initially tried what you are trying, and this (more conventional) way was super easy.

http://ckeditor.com/download

Comment: Thank U very much. This is indeed a easy way.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but here is a new answer for people directed here by a search engine...

The js is already downloaded with the package, no need to add it to your statics again, just load the js by adding

```
{{ form.media }}
```

in your templates `<form> </form>` section and RichtTextFields will be rendered using RichTextWidget (with ckeditor js). Expecting `form` to be the template variable holding the form.

Reference: https://pypi.org/project/django-ckeditor/#outside-of-django-admin